# Dynamically loading new Sprite on Scene

Tags: android, textures, andengine

I'm new to Andengine and tried to create a game with a gameplay similar to River City Ransom - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goQlPC5wOic

The Problem:
While creating the scene I load the player sprite, the backgrounds, HUD, and that's ok to load it in one go because it makes no sense to load any of those before everything else is ready.

But when I try to create a new TiledTextureRegion for a new Sprite asynchronously(A new enemy appears on the scene from the edge), there is still lag while the TextureRegion is created from assets.

Example:

```
new LoadNewEnemyOnSceneTask(enemyTexture, enemyTextureRegion, mScene, this).execute();

public class LoadNewEnemyOnSceneTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite> {


private PixelPerfectTiledTextureRegion enemyTextureRegion;
private BitmapTextureAtlas enemyTexture;
private Scene scene;
BaseGameActivity act;

public LoadNewEnemyOnSceneTask(BitmapTextureAtlas enemyTexture, PixelPerfectTiledTextureRegion       enemyTextureRegion, Scene scene, BaseGameActivity act)
{
    this.enemyTexture = enemyTexture;
    this.enemyTextureRegion = enemyTextureRegion;
    this.scene = scene;
    this.act = act;
}

@Override
protected PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite doInBackground(String... params) {
    enemyTextureRegion = PixelPerfectTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(enemyTexture, act.getAssets(), "akira.png", 0, 200, 5, 3, 0);

    PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite enemy = new PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite(480, 200, enemyTextureRegion, act.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    return enemy;
}      

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite result)
{              
    scene.attachChild(result);
}
```

}

Is this an internal Andengine bug/feature? Is there a way to load new Textures on the scene dynamically? The only information I could find was related to pre-game resource loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize, here.  Only load the TiledTextureRegion once in onLoadResources and then when creating Sprites, you can just copy (using copy() or deepCopy()) it as much as you want.  That way the costly process of actually loading the Region into memory is only done once.

- [Getting Started: working with Sprites](http://andengineguides.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/getting-started-working-with-images/)
- [Animated Srpites Deep
  copy](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/animated-srpites-deep-copy-t5710.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm glad.  I haven't been doing any AndEngine work for a while, I was really hoping my experience still applied.